# Left Outer Join With Date Range CTE Not Working As I Expect

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following LOJ query which uses a CTE to generate a range of dates:

```
Declare @inquiryStartDate DateTime;
Declare @inquiryEndDate DateTime;
Declare @inquiryMortgageNumber nvarchar(50);

SET @inquiryStartDate = '2013-07-01';
SET @inquiryEndDate = '2013-07-31';
SET @inquiryMortgageNumber = '12345678';

With DateRange As (
    SELECT ID, Date
    FROM     d_Dates
    WHERE  (Date BETWEEN @inquiryStartDate AND @inquiryEndDate)
)
Select DateRange.ID, DateRange.Date,f_MortgageSnapshots.MortgageNumber, f_MortgageSnapshots.Investor_ID
From DateRange
LEFT OUTER JOIN f_MortgageSnapshots On DateRange.ID = f_MortgageSnapshots.SnapshotDate_ID
WHERE f_MortgageSnapshots.MortgageNumber = @inquiryMortgageNumber;
```

And I'm getting this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Quick note, There are just 2 rows in the f_MortgageSnapshots table for mortgage 12345678.

[image]

---

### Solution Here!

Declare @inquiryStartDate DateTime;
Declare @inquiryEndDate DateTime;
Declare @inquiryMortgageNumber nvarchar(50);

SET @inquiryStartDate = '2013-07-01';
SET @inquiryEndDate = '2013-07-31';
SET @inquiryMortgageNumber = '7078575';

```
With DateRange As (
SELECT ID, d_Dates.Date
FROM     d_Dates
WHERE  (d_Dates.Date BETWEEN @inquiryStartDate AND @inquiryEndDate)
 )
Select DateRange.ID, DateRange.Date,f_MortgageSnapshots.MortgageNumber, f_MortgageSnapshots.Investor_ID
From DateRange Left Join f_MortgageSnapshots 
     On DateRange.ID = f_MortgageSnapshots.SnapshotDate_ID
        And  MortgageNumber = @inquiryMortgageNumber;
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, can you create a SQL fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Why is MortgageNumber = in the where clause? Why isn't it prefixed with the table or alias to help define where it comes from? This would make the problem more obvious: putting a filter for an outer joined table converts it to an inner join. You need to put that filter in the join criteria, not the where criteria.

Comment: Even if they put the WHERE criteria in the JOIN criteria they'll still end up with NULLs for the MortgageNumber and InvestorID for dates without a matching record. I think the OP is asking how to do a range of sorts so the snapshot represents values that existed when the InvestorID changed and wants to translate that into a full date list. I think you need a completely different approach than what you have. If I have time I'll write something up, but I'm guessing someone will beat me to it.

Comment: @Love2Learn that's true, but it would be a start. :-)

Comment: If you take @AaronBertrand suggestion you can get a list with the NULLs and then there are at least a dozen stackoverflow posts on how to do the other part.

Comment: @Love2Learn is correct in his assessment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
With DateRange As (
SELECT ID, Date
FROM     d_Dates
WHERE  (Date BETWEEN @inquiryStartDate AND @inquiryEndDate)
 )
   Select d.ID, d.Date, s.MortgageNumber, s.Investor_ID
   From DateRange d
      Left Join f_MortgageSnapshots s
         On d.ID = s.SnapshotDate_ID
            And  MortgageNumber = @inquiryMortgageNumber;
```

Also, you really don't need to hit a date table when using CTEs

```
With DateRange As (
SELECT ID, inquiryStartDate ADate
Union All
Select ID + 1, ADate + 1
FROM DateRange 
Where ADate < @inquiryEndDate)
Select d.ID, d.Date, s.MortgageNumber, s.Investor_ID
From DateRange d
    Left Join f_MortgageSnapshots s
        On d.ID = s.SnapshotDate_ID
           And  MortgageNumber = @inquiryMortgageNumber
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000);
```

If you want null rows to display some default value for `MortgageNumber` and `Investor_ID`,  use the `Coalesce()`  function:

```
With DateRange As (
SELECT ID, inquiryStartDate ADate
Union All
Select ID + 1, ADate + 1
FROM DateRange 
Where ADate < @inquiryEndDate)
Select d.ID, d.Date, 
   Coalesce(s.MortgageNumber, 'DefaultMortgageNumber') MortgageNumber,
   Coalesce(s.Investor_ID , -1) Investor_ID
From DateRange d
    Left Join f_MortgageSnapshots s
        On d.ID = s.SnapshotDate_ID
           And  MortgageNumber = @inquiryMortgageNumber
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000);
```

Comment: I recommend against the recursive CTE approach - a calendar table is almost always faster at the high end, and no different at the low end.

Comment: You got it.  It seems getting rid of 'Outer' and move the mortgage number from the where clause to the join did it.  I've got to find a way to fill the nulls but there should be something on Stackoverflow to handle this.  Great work Charles.  Clever.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all their help!  It's sincerely appreciated.  I'm putting the solution under the question in case it's of any help to anyone in the future.  Next I have to solve the NULLs thing.

Comment: Can anyone point me in the right direction to fill the Nulls in the Investor_ID and MortgageNumber columns?

Comment: @Daver,  The `outer` had nothing to do with it.  the keyword `Outer` is redundant and optional.  What fixed your issue was placing the predicate condition on MortgageNumber in the join conditions, (which are processed prior to adding in the null values from the outer side of the join), instead of in the where clause, which is processed after the join, and therefore causes those null rows to be removed, effectively turning the join into an Inner join again.

Comment: @Daver, for rows which do not exist in the `f_MortgageSnapshots` table, there is no value for MortgageNumber.  If you just want to replace those nulls with some default value, then use coalesce() as in my third solution.  If you need aan actual correct MortgageNumber, not some default, then there must be some other table that contains Mortgages, with MortgageNumbers, that can be used to actually connects the rows in `f_MortgageSnapshots` to a row in that mortgage table,  And then you could use that to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

I thinkg the MortgageNumber filter is actually the one from f_MortgageSnapshots. And since you have a left join, i would do something like this :

```
Declare @inquiryStartDate DateTime;
Declare @inquiryEndDate DateTime;
Declare @inquiryMortgageNumber nvarchar(50);

SET @inquiryStartDate = '2013-07-01';
SET @inquiryEndDate = '2013-07-31';
SET @inquiryMortgageNumber = '12345678';

With DateRange As (
    SELECT ID, Date
    FROM     d_Dates
    WHERE  (Date BETWEEN @inquiryStartDate AND @inquiryEndDate)
)
Select DateRange.ID, DateRange.Date,f_MortgageSnapshots.MortgageNumber, 
       f_MortgageSnapshots.Investor_ID
From DateRange
LEFT OUTER JOIN f_MortgageSnapshots On DateRange.ID 
     = f_MortgageSnapshots.SnapshotDate_ID and MortgageNumber = @inquiryMortgageNumber;
```

Comment: I ran your solution but got too many NULLs in MortgageNumber and Investor_ID without getting the values on the 7th and the 31st.  Still I think you were really close and I appreciated your help.  I'm posting the solution momentarily.  Cheers.