# Left Outer Join With Date Range Only Not Working As Expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I originally posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327150/left-outer-join-with-date-range-cte-not-working-as-i-expect) but sadly now I have to dump the mortgage number filter.  Which it turns out is a pain.

I'm using the following LOJ query which uses a CTE to generate a range of dates:

```
Declare @inquiryStartDate DateTime;
Declare @inquiryEndDate DateTime;

SET @inquiryStartDate = '2013-07-01';
SET @inquiryEndDate = '2013-07-31';

With DateRange As (
    SELECT ID, Date
    FROM     d_Dates
    WHERE  (Date BETWEEN @inquiryStartDate AND @inquiryEndDate)
)
Select DateRange.ID, DateRange.Date,f_MortgageSnapshots.MortgageNumber, f_MortgageSnapshots.Investor_ID
From DateRange
LEFT OUTER JOIN f_MortgageSnapshots On DateRange.ID = f_MortgageSnapshots.SnapshotDate_ID
```

And I'm getting something like this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Can't I do a left join between tables in the case?

Quick note, There are just 2 rows in the f_MortgageSnapshots table for mortgage 12345678.

[image]

For those who are wondering, here's the d_Dates table:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information on d_dates? Just like you did with the sanpshot table.

Comment: Sure.  I'll do that now.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: Looking at the data in f_MortgageSnapshots (just two rows) I can't see why you would expect anything to, for example, JOIN to 20130701.  There is no row in f_MortgageSnapshots with that key.  Your data is starting to look like you are looking for a FULL JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like d_dates does not contain a row for every possible date within your inquiry date range.

try something like:-

```
create function [dbo].BuildDataRange
(
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
)
returns @returntable table
(
    ID int,
    [Date] date
)
as
begin
    while @StartDate<=@EndDate begin
        insert into @returntable (ID, [Date]) values (
            DATEPART(year,@StartDate)*10000 + 
            DATEPART(month,@StartDate)*100 + 
            DATEPART(day,@StartDate),
            @StartDate)
        set @StartDate=DATEADD(day,1,@StartDate)
    end
    return
end
go
```

and then you should be able to:-

```
Declare @inquiryStartDate DateTime;
Declare @inquiryEndDate DateTime;

SET @inquiryStartDate = '2013-07-01';
SET @inquiryEndDate = '2013-07-31';

select *
from [dbo].BuildDataRange(@inquiryStartDate, @inquiryEndDate) dr
left join f_MortgageSnapshots On dr.ID = f_MortgageSnapshots.SnapshotDate_ID
```

Comment: Just looked at the original question and I think I'm way off base...  as usual...

Comment: Nah.  You may be on to something.  I'm wondering why the left outer join isn't working and you've built a date table dynamically.  Maybe that'll do it.

Comment: No joy.  Something about this join is preventing the Left side from asserting itself.  It's strange.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My solution rolls up a table of all possible dates within your inquiry range and then joins on any rows from the snapshot table where the dates match. It's not going to match anything with 20130701, for example, unless there is a row in the snapshot table for that date. If two (or more) rows in the snapshot table have the same date, the row from my function would be repeated for each match - so you would end up with multiple rows in the output for the same date - but nothing is going to JOIN to dates that don't have snapshot rows with the same date. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: You are correct.  I was expecting the a lot of nulls with mortgage number and investor id.  I have a way of filling those nulls, basically by cascading a prior non null mortgage number and investor id forward.